# Java JNA wrapper and memory consumption

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, jvm, jna

I have a question how JVM processes with JNA wrappers show memory consumption.

For example I run Java application which uses OpenCV JNA wrapper. Java application itself consumes for example 1GB of RAM and OpenCV native libs consume 3GB of RAM. 
So totally, when I will find appropriate Java JVM process(via `ps` command) it will show 1GB of RAM or 4GB(1 + 3) of RAM?

Comment: Native libs usually allocating memory using system memory allocator i.e. crt/libc malloc/free. Those virtual memory pages not managed by JVM garbage collector, which also allocating this memory from operating system.  -xms[256m] -xmx[1G] command line options limiting min/max for this memory blocks. Other words - 1 + 3 = 4 GB. Where 1GB - JVM managed memory and 3G - manual managed memory.

Comment: @VictorGubin thanks for your answer. Just to be clear, in the scenario described in my question - `ps` command for JVM process will show 4GB, correct?

Comment: Not necessary, can be less then 4G if java or OpenCV using less then 4GB in the moment. 4GB should be max total value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ps` output will show 1GB for RSS (the Resident Set Size -- how much memory is allocated to that process and is in RAM.)  The Java process will not directly show the used Native memory; however, it will appear as a portion of the VSZ (Virtual Memory Size --  all memory that the process can access, including memory that is swapped out, memory that is allocated, but not used, and memory that is from shared libraries.)

For example, I wrote the following code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Memory;

public class TinyJavaBigC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Grab 1 GiB of memory
        Memory buf = new Memory(1 << 30);
        // Sleep long enough to grab ps
    }
}
```

Regardless of the amount of Native memory reserved using `new Memory(bytes)` (which effectively calls `malloc`) the Java application consistently used the same amount memory in RSS, and limiting the Java heap size using `-Xmx` did not prevent allocation of native memory beyond this limit.  The 1 GiB of native memory clearly disappeared from the OS's "available" memory, however.

I placed the above code in a loop incrementing the shift left value for allocation, and ran it using `-Xmx512m` which should have limited JVM heap to 512 MiB.  The RSS, which includes all JVM Stack and Heap Memory, remained in the ~50 MiB range.  The allocated memory does show up in `VSZ` associated with the process.  As this also includes other types of memory it's not a direct measure, and vastly exceeds the available RAM and swapfile size constraints but it does at least give some indication of increased allocation.

```
Native Memory          RSS          VSZ
       1 byte     42.0 MiB      9.6 GiB
      2 bytes     45.8 MiB      9.6 GiB
      4 bytes     46.0 MiB      9.6 GiB
      8 bytes     46.1 MiB      9.6 GiB
     16 bytes     46.3 MiB      9.6 GiB
     32 bytes     46.5 MiB      9.6 GiB
     64 bytes     47.0 MiB      9.6 GiB
    128 bytes     47.5 MiB      9.6 GiB
    256 bytes     47.6 MiB      9.6 GiB
    512 bytes     48.9 MiB      9.6 GiB
        1 KiB     49.1 MiB      9.6 GiB
        2 KiB     49.2 MiB      9.6 GiB
        4 KiB     49.3 MiB      9.6 GiB
        8 KiB     49.3 MiB      9.6 GiB
       16 KiB     49.8 MiB      9.6 GiB
       32 KiB     50.1 MiB      9.6 GiB
       64 KiB     50.1 MiB      9.6 GiB
      128 KiB     50.6 MiB      9.6 GiB
      256 KiB     51.4 MiB      9.6 GiB
      512 KiB     51.3 MiB      9.6 GiB
        1 MiB     51.4 MiB      9.6 GiB
        2 MiB     51.4 MiB      9.6 GiB
        4 MiB     51.4 MiB      9.6 GiB
        8 MiB     51.4 MiB      9.6 GiB
       16 MiB     51.3 MiB      9.7 GiB
       32 MiB     51.3 MiB      9.7 GiB
       64 MiB     51.7 MiB      9.8 GiB
      128 MiB     51.7 MiB      9.9 GiB
      256 MiB     51.6 MiB     10.1 GiB
      512 MiB     51.6 MiB     10.5 GiB
        1 GiB     51.7 MiB     11.3 GiB
        2 GiB     51.8 MiB     12.8 GiB
        4 GiB     51.9 MiB     15.8 GiB
        8 GiB     51.9 MiB     21.8 GiB
       16 GiB     52.0 MiB     33.8 GiB
       32 GiB     52.0 MiB     57.8 GiB
       64 GiB     52.1 MiB    105.8 GiB
      128 GiB     52.1 MiB    201.8 GiB
      256 GiB     52.5 MiB    393.8 GiB
      512 GiB     52.6 MiB    777.8 GiB
        1 TiB     52.7 MiB      1.5 TiB
        2 TiB     52.7 MiB      3.0 TiB
        4 TiB     52.8 MiB      6.0 TiB
        8 TiB     52.9 MiB     12.0 TiB
       16 TiB     53.1 MiB     24.0 TiB
       32 TiB     53.2 MiB     48.0 TiB
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot allocate 70368744177664 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how about the following article https://blogs.vmware.com/apps/2011/06/taking-a-closer-look-at-sizing-the-java-process.html where “other mem”(which is also part of JVM memory) contains memory for JNI?

Comment: You asked about `ps` and I answered about `ps`. The memory does show up in `VSZ` but not in `RSS` and is not constrained by JVM heap size `-Xmx` switch.

Comment: Thanks! So in order to see the memory allocated by JVM process(heap size + JNI) I should look into `VSZ` with something like `ps -opid,rss,vsz –p <Java PID>`?

Comment: Yep, that could work... note there's a lot more to VSZ than just that but it will at least give you some visibility.  Also note that in my loop it looks like the native memory hadn't gotten around to releasing itself.  The final allocation of 48TiB is closer to the sum of the previous 2 (16+32 TiB).  Also I only have 16 GiB of actual memory and a 500 GB hard drive, so I'm not sure where it was finding 48 TiB of memory to allocate!  Nonetheless... there you have it. :)